# Unable to set a perfect image for swift spritekit background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is my first time to make a game with spritekit and swift , and I'm having a problem with a Scene size and the background image for the GameScene and the LaunchScreen. Currently, I'm using a screen size of

```
  let scene = TitleScene(size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334))
```

I prepared 3 background images for the scene , main.png = 750 × 1334
  main@2x.png = 640 × 1136, main@3x.png = 960 × 1685

I've read multiple swift game tutorials but I cannot find a solution for supporting the screen sizes for all iphones. When I set the background for the TitleSecen with

```
var bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "main")

        self.addChild(bgImage)
        bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
```

When I use the script above the  screen gets centered and small. What size should I set the image for the background? The image for the LaunchScreen is also strange as well. I've there is a really good tutorial or a example for a noob like me it will be helpful! 
I would love to here from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your image sizes are everywhere, and I don't think you understand how Xs work.

Basically, they are the ratios of which the resolution increases based on the device tipe (non-retina, retina, retina HD).

Let's take an example.

You need an image for a button. You support iPhone, from the iPhone 3gs to the 6 Plus. That means you have all 3 types of displays supported.

Your button is 50x50 points. A point = 1 pixel x resolution ratio

- the iPhone 3Gs is non retina, it has a ration of 1 (1 pixel in a point), so your image should be 50x50 pixels => image@1x.png = 50x50 pixels
- the 4, 4s, 5 and 5s are retina, they have a ration of 2 (2 pixels in a point), so your image should be 100x100 pixels => image@2x.png = 100x100 pixels
- the 6 and 6+ are RetinaHD, they have a ratio of 3 (3 pixels in a point), so your image should be 150x150 pixels  => image@3x.png = 150x150 pixels

You should read the [iOS UI Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Secondly, in your case, the image is 750 x 1334. So image@2x should be 1500 x 2668 and image@3x 2250 x 4002.

Comment: Thank you!  Your explanation is great!